# Failed upgrade: MySQL on WampServer

Tags: mysql, upgrade, wampserver

I have tried a couple of times, on separate occasions, to upgrade MySQL version from 5.6.17 to 5.6.25 on WAMPserver.

Each time the upgrade is unsuccessful:

```
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

The only feedback left in the upgrade_result.txt file is:

```
Looking for 'mysql.exe' as: c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.25\bin\mysql.exe
Looking for 'mysqlcheck.exe' as: c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.25\bin\mysqlcheck.exe
```

Both files exist.
I follow the only instructions I have been able to find posted in the WampServer forum over two years ago: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,111797,124054

If anyone knows how to deal with this, please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The linked question has no connection whatsoever to upgrading MySQL, whether successfully or not, on an existing working WampServer installation.

Comment: It's not normally necessary to run mysql_upgrade if you are upgrading within minor releases. All you need to do is backup you databases using 5.6.17 and restore them using 5.6.25. `mysql-upgrade` is normally only for when you are moving from say 5.6 to 5.7.

Comment: I didn't know upgrading was unnecessary between minor releases. The reason why I wanted to upgrade was that I was hoping the newer version might have better protection for unexpected shut downs. Over the past year, there have been at least five power cuts where I live, and each time there is one, and WampServer is running, the MySQL service won't start afterwards, the only solution being to reinstall WAMP. Reinstalling is easy - it only takes 2-3 minutes but the bigger problem is that **all innoDB tables are destroyed**. This is why I wanted to upgrade.

Comment: But now I have actually **managed to upgrade successfully**... WampSever could detect the new MySQL version before but it was unable to start the service (orange icon). So I looked at the `Mycomp.err` file inside the `data` folder, found out there were a few innoDB tables that were causing problems (because they were broken after the last power cut). Deleted these tables completely, and the MySQL service started OK, the WAMP icon turning green. **I didn't need to run the `mysql_upgrade` command.**

Comment: I think you need to study up on INNODB backup and recovery mechanisms. Its a far more complex database that MYISAM but recovery from failures like this is part of the basic methodology of INNODB, but you need to know what you are doing with it to make it all work properly

Comment: I tried following some innoDB tables recovery advice found here but unsuccessfully. So I decided to switch to MyISAM instead. I suppose at some point I will try to learn more about innoDB and the recovery procedure but I don't have the time now.
Thanks for your time!